# img srcset doesn't work

Tags: html, image, srcset

Can't seem to get this to work. Currently only the full-size img (soho-w920h665) loads. 
What I'm trying to do: the img spans 100vw until window width is 766px or bigger, then the img spans only 50vw.

```
<img 
   srcset="/img/soho-w500h361.jpg 500,
           /img/soho-w700h605.jpg 700,
           /img/soho-w920h665.jpg 920"

    sizes="(min-width : 766px) 50vw, 

    data-src="/img/soho-w920h665.jpg
    ">
```

Comment: Just a stab, but is "w" for "inherent width in pixels", e.g. `/img/soho-w500h361.jpg 500w` required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using the right syntax for it, `src` attribute seems to be missing for now. An example of correct syntax would be -

```
<img src="clock-demo-thumb-200.png" 
     alt="Clock" 
     srcset="clock-demo-thumb-200.png 200w,
             clock-demo-thumb-400.png 400w"
     sizes="(min-width: 600px) 200px, 50vw">
```

so double check your `data-src` attribute. Look into MDN documentation for better insight here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img